# How to extract NA from character vector

Tags: r

i actually try to produce a formula from all possible combinations of features.
Here is a sample code

```
namen<-expand.grid(c("weight",NA), c("height",NA),c("width",NA),c("volume",NA), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
namen2<-as.data.frame(namen)
```

gives me a data frame with all possible combinations of the features WEIGHT, HEIGHT, WIDTH and VOLUME

```
for(i in 1:nrow(namen2)){  assign(paste("a", i, sep = ""), namen2[i,])}
```

does give me vectors with the desired combinations

for example

```
a7
a7q<-t(as.data.frame(a7[!is.na(a7)]))
a7q
a7f<-as.formula(paste("type~",paste(a7q,collapse="+")))
a7f
```

is fine

but i have no clue how to do this in a loop for all possible combinations.

This is my try:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(namen2)){assign(paste("a", i,"q", sep = ""), {eval(parse(text=paste("a",i,sep="")[!is.na(paste("a",i,sep=""))]))})}
```

But this includes NAs

Do you have any idea??

Comment: You can create the dataframe also in one step: `namen <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(c("weight",NA), c("height",NA),c("width",NA),c("volume",NA), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will return a list with formulas of all possible combinations based on `namen`:

```
l <- apply(head(namen, -1), 1, function(x)
               reformulate(paste(na.omit(x), collapse = "+"), response = "type"))
```

You can access the list elements of list `l` with `[[`, e.g., `l[[1]]` returns

```
type ~ weight + height + width + volume
<environment: 0x104298318>`
```

Comment: This really looks great! Exactly what i wanted to do!!
THANKS A LOT!!